# How does reference counting work on a deeply nested, non cyclical object?

Tags: garbage-collection, reference-counting

Say you have this sort of structure, but imagine it was super deeply nested like 20 levels deep:

```
function getIt() {
  let a = { hello: 'world' }
  let b = { foo: 'bar', deeply: { nested: true } }
  a.b = b
  // stuff
  a.b = null
  return a
}

let x = getIt()
```

The `a.b` is no longer needed by the end of the function, so `b` can be garbage collected. There  are no cyclic dependencies. What happens exactly in a [reference counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) to garbage collect `b`? Does it have to go through potentially thousands of nested objects (if `b` was thousands of nested objects deep) and decrement the counts on each of them, or can it just say we can tell from the structure somehow that since `a.b = null` that everything attached to it can be cleared. How does this work, and how is it typically optimized in a reference counting system like in Swift or others?

Comment: You have to traverse the object graph anyway, to perform the actual delete/freeing operation on each object. That operation outweighs the update of a counter. Yes, that means reference counting is not an efficient memory management solution. It offers more determinism, but not more performance.

Comment: Does a mark and sweep system have this same problem?

Comment: This depends on how it is implemented. First, mark and sweep may have a smaller impact as it doesn’t need to take action on every reference variable change. It only needs to traverse references when the memory is exhausted or it may run when some heuristics tells that it is a good time for it. Then, most implementations transfer the still reachable objects into a new space, reclaiming the old space as a whole. That way, there’s no freeing action per object but this one action for all of them. The efficiency depends on how often it needs to run, i.e. more memory available → less overhead.